# HTML/CSS/JS in desktop applications

Tags: c#, html, cordova, desktop-application

I've read about XSS vulnerability in desktop applications like Skype and ICQ.
I wonder why they choose to use html in this kind of applications that can also be written without any html. Is there a simple reason?
Does someone know if Skype uses html on pages like "Skype Home" only or is the whole GUI written in html?

I'm asking because I'm writing a web application that runs within the browser and will be ported to mobile and desktop platforms once finished. You can compare it to instant messengers but it's something different in fact.

I thought about using PhoneGap to simply "copy" the project to mobile platforms and using system functions via the PhoneGap API. But I think it may be slow and/or not good-looking. Also it wouldn't look native, the question then is whether too use our own html GUI on all platforms (so it looks the same everywhere) or to adapt the design concepts of each platform (using native controls in native languages or e.g. Titanium (which is unfortunately too expensive)).

But I never thought about using HTML in desktop applications. How do you embed that anyway? I'm using C#. Using WebBrowser form element or using some kind of web browser rendering engine?

Comment: Mozilla XUL Runner and Adobe AIR are two ways to write desktop apps using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Comment: @Eliasdx did any of the answers below resolve your issue? If so please mark appropriately.

Comment: Also please try to stick to one question per post, this is not the place for general musings :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the initial question (in your 1st paragraph):

I assume they chose to wrote it using HTML as a way to make it cross-platform more easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make desktop applications using purely HTML/CSS/JS and have them looking native. However you can use Sencha Touch to make your Phonegap applications look native (to an extent).

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla Prism was written with this idea in mind: http://prism.mozillalabs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Appcelerator Titanium Desktop/Mobile. They have a similar idea there - http://www.appcelerator.com/

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the WebBrowser control to basically host an internet explorer session in your windows application.  This is platform specific, but there is a commercial version which is available for some smartphones: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_(software)#MonoTouch_and_Mono_for_Android.

You can make an HTML5 application which will give you a lot of the benefits of a fat client while maximizing portability with smartphones.  You can still have the user save the application to the desktop: http://miniapps.co.uk/installation/.  But, that's clunky and, like the desbest said, it will run in a web browser.  If you want to maximize the customization, then it looks like PhoneGap is an choice worth taking a look at to me as well.